# How to know if a given user has read and/or write permissions for a given path

Tags: shell, unix, user-permissions, directory-permissions

I should start by saying I consider myself a proficient user. But today I had the need to automate this and was stumped.

Let's suppose I am root, and as such I'm able to traverse the whole filesystem but I can't run "sudo" nor "su".

I have a given user and a given path.

How can I check, over the CLI, whether the user will be able to read and/or write to the path?

I know this sounds easy, but keep in mind that:

- We're not, nor can we become, the user.
- We can't just rely on the final directory permissions, as permissions higher up the path may be blocking access to the final directory.
- We can't just rely just on the directory group permissions either, in this age of inherited groups.

I'm assuming this can't be done through any command, and I'd need to first gather all user groups, then traverse the whole hierarchy of the path, check read permissions all along the path and then read & write for the final directory. Sounds awfully expensive, though.

Comment: Your assumptions look valid from here. Don't forget execute permissions for the directory.

Comment: i don't see why you shouldn't be able to `su`

Comment: hop: Whatever the reason, that's the problem statement. "Can't use x" can't be answered by "then use x". This problem in real life comes if you want to let the user know if the share they're creating would not be readable to the users they're giving access to. For example, when creating a guest-accessible shared folder (whose user behind the scenes is, really, "nobody") that the guests won't be able to read or write to.

Comment: @hop: "I don't have this problem in real life" doesn't necessarily equal "this is not a real-life problem".

Comment: @Eduo: this site is not for posing puzzles.

Comment: Piskvor: I'm assuming I'll have to do the traversing. Thanks for the executable bit reminder. It's just to expensive that I wanted to find some other, better, more efficient way.

Comment: @Eduo: sorry, I can't even parse your last comment. anyway, just give the user a tool that sets everything up correctly, then there is no need to check.

Comment: I'm not posing puzzles. I don't know a better answer than the one I hinted at. I need to provide a functionality for a user to know if the folder they're choosing to share is readable through the front-end they're using. The file sharing mechanism runs as root but not the front-end. A user may use the front-end to create a new share for which he himself has no access to. So the front-end should let the user know if the final users able to use the share will be able to. There you have it. I'm sorry if you can't "parse" this comment either, I don't know how much clearer to make it.

Comment: @hop, if this is no real-world problem, then please explain why, with another OS (Windows), the shell even has a specific feature designed to let you [view effective file system permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758822(v=ws.10).aspx)  for any given user. This feature can be really handy in some situations, e.g. to save your users from a trial-and-error process.

Comment: is it possible for you to set `euid`, or do you consider that to be the same as becoming the user?

Comment: @stakx: ACLs are a different animal altogether

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tag me a scripting guru!

```
check_access() {
  checked_file=$1
  target_user=$2
  result=PASS

  groups=`id -G $target_user | sed -e 's| | -o -group |g' -e 's|^|\\( -group |' -e 's|$| \\)|'`

  while [ $checked_file != / ]; do 
    find $checked_file -maxdepth 0 \
      -type f \( \
        \( -user $target_user -perm 0400 \) \
        -o \( $groups -perm 0040 \) \
        -o -perm 0004 \
      \) -o -type d \( \
        \( -user $target_user -perm 0100 \) \
        -o \( $groups -perm 0010 \) \
        -o -perm 0001 \
      \) >/dev/null 2>&1 || result=FAIL
    checked_file=`dirname $checked_file`
  done
  echo $result
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the best way is to validate via user himself:

```
if sudo su - $user_to_check -c "[[ -r $path_to_check ]]"
then echo "$user_to_check can read $path_to_check"
else echo "$user_to_check can not read $path_to_check"
fi
if sudo su - $user_to_check -c "[[ -w $path_to_check ]]"
then echo "$user_to_check can write $path_to_check"
else echo "$user_to_check can not write $path_to_check"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot actually provide a full answer, and I can't add anything substantial to your own ideas, except perhaps this:

I suspect that a general approach to checking effective access rights does not exist, simply because access rights depend heavily on the underlying file system(s). For example, checking access rights works quite differently on file systems that use the standard Unix `rwx` flags (e.g. Linux' ext2, ext3) than with file systems that support ACLs (such as [XFS](http://oss.sgi.com/projects/xfs/) or NTFS).

There might be *several specific* command-line tools that do what you want to do for specific file system types. (Analogy: tools such as `fsck`, `mkfs` may exist per file system type.)

Especially with UNIX-like operating systems, where all kinds of file systems can be mounted in one big directory structure, assuming only one specific permissions mechanism might lead to problems.

If you build your own solution for this problem, think about this fact first, then decide exactly which access right mechanism(s) you want to support. (I'm not sure, but I could imagine that Unix / the POSIX specification prescribes the `rwx` access rights flags as a minimum that every Unix should support.)

Answer (score 0):

`ls -l <file-name or dir-name>`

> Suppose you want to check the permissions for uploads directory.Enter
>   `ls -l uploads`
>   This will result like this

```
total 20
drwxrwxr-x 2 tomcat ec2-user 4096 Nov  5 04:21 deals
drwxrwxr-x 2 tomcat ec2-user 4096 Nov  5 04:25 gallery-images
drwxrwxr-x 3 tomcat ec2-user 4096 Nov  5 04:25 hotels
drwxrwxr-x 3 tomcat ec2-user 4096 Nov  5 04:28 rooms
drwxrwxr-x 3 tomcat ec2-user 4096 Nov  5 04:32 temp
```

Comment: If you think it is the correct answer can you elaborate on why please.

Comment: Using `ls -l <file-name or dir-name>` you can get the permissions for every user @G